# How exactly works this Observable behavior in this Angular 2 example?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, javascript-framework, angular2-observables

I am not so into JavaScript\TypeScript and I have the following doubt about how exactly works this piece of code:

```
  onGet() {
    this.serverService.getServers()
      .subscribe(
        (servers: any[]) => this.servers = servers,   // an array of anything (or an array of server)
        (error) => console.log(error)
      );
  }
```

From what I can undestood the **onGet()** method is calling the **getServers()** method that returns an **Observable, so it is subscribing this returned Observable object.

From what I know the Observable concept is: when something change on this object (when an event is fired, correct me if I am doing wrong assertion), perform the code related to an anonymous inner function.

But here I am not so sure about the exact meaning of this piece of code and how to correctly read it:

```
    (servers: any[]) => this.servers = servers,   // an array of anything (or an array of server)
    (error) => console.log(error)
```

Can you help me to understand how exactly works?

Comment: What precisely do you not understand? The typings? The arrow function syntax? Have you read e.g. http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html? See e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253894/3001761 and be more specific.

Comment: I found a very good explanation on observables here https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/using_observables.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(servers: any[]) => this.servers = servers,   // an array of anything (or an array of server)
(error) => console.log(error)
```

is equivalent to

```
(servers: any[]) => { //success callback
       this.servers = servers;   // an array of anything (or an array of server)
},
(error) => { //error callback
        console.log(error);
}
```

First one is the `success` callback and second one is the `error` callback which are executed based on the result returned by `getServers()`

Comment: The inline form also *returns* the result.

Comment: Yes it does. I have just put that into more readable format. That was the actual user question.

Comment: My point is that your equivalents do not. Also it's not clear that this *is* the OP's actual question.

Answer (score 0):

```
   // this function will resolve for a response, which is not an error
   (servers: any[]) => this.servers = servers,
   // this will resolve if the response is an error:
   //either a http error or thrown error
   (error) => console.log(error)
```

Presumably, the call to `serverService` request a list of servers and the `this.servers` is set from that list. In case of an error (like 4XX or 5XX errors), the console will display the error. The observable will be resolved and closed in any case. For a "living" observable, which can be updated at some point of time later, one would use some type of a `Subject`.